# Error 404 upon AJAX call to async Task<ActionResult> in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to make an `aJax Call` (View-side) to an `async Task<> function` on the Controller-side and returning the result back to the ajax call for some other functions later on.

**Controller Snippet**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using System.Security.Claims;

    public class DataController : Controller
    {
        private UserManager<AppUser> _userManager { get; }
        private SignInManager<AppUser> _signInManager { get; }
        public CSVController(SignInManager<AppUser> signInManager, UserManager<vFarmAppUser> userManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
        }

        public async Task<ActionResult> RetrieveDataAsync(string time)
        {
            var count = 0;
            using (var context = new DataDbContext())
            {
                proxyRecords = context.Datas.ToList();
                count = proxyRecords.Count();
            }

            var userId = this.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name);
            Console.WriteLine(userId);
            AppUser user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(userId);

            var metaHolder = new ModelClass
            {
                UniqueId = 1000,
                dataTime = time,
                RecordNo = count,
                Topic = user.Topic
            };
            Console.WriteLine(metaHolder);
            return Json(metaHolder);
        }
    }
```

**View Snippet**

```
<div style="width: 100%; width: 1100px; background-color: none">
    <div>
        <button id="btnSave" class="btn btn-primary">Save Data</button>
    </div>
</div>    
@section Scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
        $(document).ready(function () {
            Init();
        });

        function Init() {
            _oRecord = [];
            _metaData = [];

            $("#btnSave").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '../Data/RetrieveProxy/',
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (result) {
                        _oRecords = result;
                        var d = new Date();
                        var getDate = [d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDay()].map((a) => (a < 10 ? '0' + a : a));
                        var getJoinedDate = getDate.join(':');
                        var getTime = [d.getHours(), d.getMinutes(), d.getSeconds()].map((a) => (a < 10 ? '0' + a : a));
                        var getJoinedTime = getTime.join(':');
                        var getDateTime = getJoinedDate + "-" + getJoinedTime;

                        RetrieveDataFoo(getDateTime);                    
                    },
                });
            });
        };

        function RetrieveDataFoo(getDateTime) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '../CSV/RetrieveDataAsync/',
                    type: "POST",
                    data: { time: getDateTime },

                    success: function (result) {
                        _metaDatas = result;
                        alert(JSON.stringify(_metaDatas));
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        alert(error.statusText);
                    }
                });
        };
    </script>
}
```

Currently, the 1st ajax call to `/Data/RetrieveProxy/` works perfectly fine but the 2nd ajax call does not work. I was trying to solve it by following this [Post](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/14716) but to no avail, unfortunately.

Comment: *"is there a special tag needed for AJAX to call Async functions"* - No. 404 is a server-side error. Either your URL is wrong, or the server is not happy with the request for another reason.

Comment: Also. **Never** use `async: false` in Ajax requests. The other request options you're setting make no sense for these requests. either: GET requests have no content type, drop the `contentType: "application/json"`. You *want* data to be processed by jQuery. Drop the `processData: false`. The server will send a proper response data type, drop the `dataType: "json"`. The server *should* send proper caching headers (if it doesn't, make it do that). Drop the `cache: false`.

Comment: Finally: get rid of the global variables `_oRecord` and `_metaData`. Asynchronous code does not work that way.

Comment: Thanks for that, I just realised how weird that config was as well - I have updated the new config. However, it still does not work, Error 404.

Comment: Hard to say, other than that you're obviously using a URL/route that is not defined in your application. Enable detailed error logging on the server side, look at the responses you get. Are you sure the trailing `/` are necessary for these URLs? They look weird, but I don't know ASP.NET MVC, so I'm not sure. (Now that you've switched from GET to POST requests, you probably do need `contentType: "application/json"`, and `data: JSON.stringify({time: ...})`.)

Comment: Turns out I just need to change the URL to not include `Async` as mentioned in the UPDATE of the post, thanks once again for your help!

Comment: Don't update your question to include the answer. Write the answer below. Answering your own questions is perfectly fine on SO.

Comment: (Kudos for figuring it out.)

Answer (score 2):

Turns out, I just needed to ignore the Async in the URL as mentioned [here](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/14716), i.e., ../CSV/RetrieveData/ instead of ../CSV/RetrieveDataAsync/.

**Updated View Snippet**

```
        function RetrieveDataFoo(getDateTime) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '../CSV/RetrieveData/',     // Does not have `Async` suffix
                    type: "POST",
                    data: { time: getDateTime },

                    success: function (result) {
                        _metaDatas = result;
                        alert(JSON.stringify(_metaDatas));
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        alert(error.statusText);
                    }
                });
        };
```

**Controller Snippet - Function Name**

```
        # Inclusion of `Async` Suffix as part of VSTHRD200 .net Guideline
        public async Task<ActionResult> RetrieveDataAsync(string time)
        {
              // Do Async Stuff
        }
```